# Trouble creating nested merged dictionaries using SharedResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary, mergeddictionaries

I have an assembly called `Atelis.Base.Wpf.Resources`. It is a DLL that holds resource dictionaries.

Within this assembly I have defined a `SharedResourceDictionary`:

```
namespace Atelis.Base.Wpf.Resources
{

/// <summary>
/// The shared resource dictionary is a specialized resource dictionary
/// that loads it content only once. If a second instance with the same source
/// is created, it only merges the resources from the cache.
/// </summary>
public class SharedResourceDictionary : ResourceDictionary
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Internal cache of loaded dictionaries 
    /// </summary>
    public static Dictionary<Uri, ResourceDictionary> _sharedDictionaries =
        new Dictionary<Uri, ResourceDictionary>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Local member of the source uri
    /// </summary>
    private Uri _sourceUri;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the uniform resource identifier (URI) to load resources from.
    /// </summary>
    public new Uri Source
    {
        get { return _sourceUri; }
        set
        {
            try
            {
                _sourceUri = new Uri(value.OriginalString);
            }
            catch
            {
                // do nothing?
            }

            if (!_sharedDictionaries.ContainsKey(value))
            {
                // If the dictionary is not yet loaded, load it by setting
                // the source of the base class
                base.Source = value;

                // add it to the cache
                _sharedDictionaries.Add(value, this);
            }
            else
            {
                // If the dictionary is already loaded, get it from the cache
                MergedDictionaries.Add(_sharedDictionaries[value]);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I then have a number of resource dictionary files like so:

Styles.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<!-- styles are defined here -->
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Colors.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                >

    <Color x:Key="Color1">#FF000000</Color>
    <!-- ... many more colors and brushes are defined here -->
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Buttons.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Atelis.Base.Wpf.Resources"
>
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <local:SharedResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Atelis.Base.Wpf.Resources;component/Colors.xaml"/>
    <local:SharedResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Atelis.Base.Wpf.Resources;component/Styles.xaml"/>           
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<!-- a ton of button styles are defined here -->

</ResourceDictionary>
```

DataTemplates.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:base="clr-namespace:Atelis.Base.Client;assembly=Atelis.Base.Wpf"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Atelis.Base.Wpf.Resources"
                >

<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <local:SharedResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Atelis.Base.Wpf.Resources;component/Buttons.xaml"/>
    <local:SharedResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Atelis.Base.Wpf.Resources;component/Colors.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<!-- a ton of templates are defined here -->

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Everything is good until I get to `DataTemplates.xaml`. The `Buttons.xaml` `SharedResourceDictionary` is giving me an inline warning ***"Cannot create unknown type '{clr-namespace:Atelis.Base.Wpf.Resources}SharedResourceDictionary'."*** And when I try to define a `staticresource` style I get another xaml warning ***"The resource 'ButtonStyle2' cannot be resolved."***

I think it is important to notice that the other `SharedResourceDictionary` declarations whose source URI do not contain `SharedResourceDictionaries` do not have this problem (I can add Colors and Styles to dictionary declarations without any warnings and the resources resolve when set).

The application works just fine, but I cannot seem to get visual studio to resolve this resource and remove the warning. It is a small inconvenience but I am curious to know why it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if what you're doing is even possible.

AFAIK, here are two different methods

```
<local:Foo x:Key="Bar" />
```

and

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="Baz" />
```

but yours is like a blend of both.

The trick is, if you receive a ***"The resource 'ButtonStyle2' cannot be resolved."***, make sure you don't have any other errors and try building your project. Most of the time my statement is valid but compiler complains about it until I build it in XAML.

You could also merge these two type mentioned above as well such as below.

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Baz" />
  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  <local:Foo x:Key="Bar" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```